# How do I click this button in VB to redirect the page?

Tags: javascript, java, vba, excel

Given the html source below, how can click on it in VBA in order to redirect the page?  I am creating a macro in excel that can click through a site and scrape data from the next page.

```
<DIV id=mopLYR>
<A onmouseover="javascript:k.src='/x.jpg';document.mopIMG.src=k.src;" 

onmouseout="javascript:k.src='/x.jpg';document.mopIMG.src=k.src;" 
href="javascript:mainMenuSubmit

('mop_mis');"><IMG border=0 name=mopIMG src="http://x.jpg"></A>
</DIV>
```

My code doesn't give me any errors but it isn't redirecting. I also tried to make a loop to find  the element ID but was unable to get anywhere with it.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim div As HTMLDivElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate ("http://x.com.WisServlet")

'Wait for Load to finish
While IE.readyState <> "complete"
DoEvents
Wend

Set butn = IE.document.getElementById("mopLYR")

butn.Click
```

Comment: There is no code, in your question.

Comment: Please provide, the code where you try to do the task, the errors you get, and how you tried to fixed, and we will glad to help you. In the way you originally post the question, is vague and imcomplete. Please read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the id of the `<div>` element, not the hyperlink so the 'click' will not work on it.
You need to reference the hyperlink but since it has no 'id' attribute you need another way to find it.
Try referencing the `div` first:

```
Set div = IE.document.getElementById("mopLYR")
```

Then inside it, find the hyperlink. You will get a collection of `<a>` and you need to loop through it to find you link:

```
For Each btn in div.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If btn.getAttribute("href") = "javascript:mainMenuSubmit('mop_mis');" Then
        btn.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: I was able to get the loop to run, however, I get the same response from the site. The page doesn't redirect.  I can't seem to get the code to click on anything so I must not be specifying right.  If btn is ie.document.getElementById("mopLYR"), is this even clickable or what is the clickable portion in the source code?

Comment: The clickable element is `<a>` nested inside `<div>`. The purpose of the loop is to find the `<a>` based on its "href" attribute (it does not have the "id" so we cannot find it the same way we did for the `<div>`). Once it finds the `<a>`, it will click it.